# Incorrect opening flash content from the wall

Tags: facebook, flash, share

I publish swf with feed or stream.publish methods.

```
var data={
    method: "feed",
    display: "iframe",
    source: swfUrl,
    picture: picUrl, 
    name: name,
    caption: caption,
    actions: actions
};

FB.ui(data, callback);
```

In some facebook accounts this swf will open in a new browser tab, in some - on the wall (this is right).

How to avoid opening in a new tab?

Answer (score 0):

If it's still a current question: All urls should be in https, when a user accesses FB via https and your flash is served via http a new tab will be opened.